# I want to declare an empty array in Java and then I want do update it but the code is not working

Tags: java, arrays

I want to declare an empty array in Java and then I want do update it but the code is not working.

```
public class JavaConversion {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int array[] = {};
        int number = 5, i = 0, j = 0;

        while (i < 4) {
            array[i] = number;
            i = i + 1;
        }

        while (j < 4) {
            System.out.println(array[j]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to give the array a size...

Comment: Creating an empty array means that all slots are empty, BUT you have at least to provide the number of slots.

Comment: When declaring an array, it's best practice to place the brackets directly after the type, i.e. `int[] array`.

Comment: I want an array whose size is not constant

Comment: it seems you are coming from another languajes where arrays can be resized, arrays in java have a fixed size which has to be declared when created. maybe you find 'ArrayList<>' more useful, which behaves more like another languajes arrays the ones you seem to be more used to. anyway, they can hold just one type of value as java is a strong typed languaje.

Answer (score 39):

You are creating an array of zero length (no slots to put anything in)

```
 int array[]={/*nothing in here = array with no slots*/};
```

and then trying to assign values to array slots (which you don't have, because there are none)

```
array[i] = number; //array[i] = element i in the array of length 0
```

You need to define a larger array to fit your needs

```
 int array[] = new int[4]; //Create an array with 4 elements [0],[1],[2] and [3] each containing an int value
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get an error saying "Generic array creation" when I do `SomeClass array[] = new SomeClass[4];`.

Comment: @DonaldDuck it sounds like your `SomeClass` is a generic type (e.g. `SomeClass<SomeOtherClass>`) which isn't supported for arrays in Java.

Answer (score 15):

Your code compiles just fine. However, your array initialization line is wrong:

```
int array[]={};
```

What this does is declare an array with a size equal to the number of elements in the brackets. Since there is nothing in the brackets, you're saying the size of the array is 0 - this renders the array completely useless, since now it can't store anything.

Instead, you can either initialize the array right in your original line:

```
int array[] = { 5, 5, 5, 5 };
```

Or you can declare the size and then populate it:

```
int array[] = new int[4];
// ...while loop
```

If you don't know the size of the array ahead of time (for example, if you're reading a file and storing the contents), you should use an `ArrayList` instead, because that's an array that grows in size dynamically as more elements are added to it (in layman's terms).

Answer (score 9):

You need to give the array a size:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int array[] = new int[4];
    int number = 5, i = 0,j = 0;
    while (i<4){
        array[i]=number;
        i=i+1;
    }
    while (j<4){
        System.out.println(array[j]);
        j++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

So the issue is in your array declaration you are declaring an empty array with the empty curly braces{} instead of an array that allows slots.

Roughly speaking, there can be three types of inputs:

1. `int array[] = null;` - Does not point to any memory locations so is a null arrau
2. `int array[] = {}` - which is sort of equivalent to `int array[] = new int[0];`
3. `int array[] = new int[n]` where `n` is some number indicating the number of
   memory locations in the array

Answer (score 3):

You can try creating new array at every iteration with a size greater than in the previous iteration.
i.e.

```
public class JavaConversion
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int array[]=new int[0];
        int number = 5, i = 0,j = 0;
        while (i<4) {
            array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + 1);
            array[i]=number;
            i=i+1;
        }
        while (j<4) {
            System.out.println(array[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a number in an arbitrary place in the array without telling the array how big it needs to be. For your example: `int[] array = new int[4];`

Comment: <1 minute too slow ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do some thing like this,

Initialize with empty array and assign the values later

```
String importRt = "23:43 43:34";
if(null != importRt) {
            importArray = Arrays.stream(importRt.split(" "))
                    .map(String::trim)
                    .toArray(String[]::new);
        }

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(exportImportArray));
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 2):

It is better for that operation use ArrayList